# How to create a bunch of useless ssids?

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi-os

I am playing around and want to create a bunch of wifi networks that if you join them, have no internet access or anything. I have seen an Arduino script for this, but not for the raspberry pi, and I'm not sure how to port a script from the Arduino to a RasPi. Is there any way to achieve this? I am also using raspberry pi os lite on a Raspberry Pi Zero W.

Edit: [Original Script](https://github.com/spacehuhn/esp8266_beaconSpam/blob/master/esp8266_beaconSpam/esp8266_beaconSpam.ino)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to indicate what you already tried in porting the Arduino scripts to the Raspberry PI, and where you faced problems. That way you can ensure contributors don't suggest solutions you already know won't work. It will also help contributors assess what tools you have available/are comfortable with.

Comment: Does the WiFi networks normally provide internet access and you only want that the RasPi cannot connect to the internet? Are there networks that the RasPi can use to access the internet? How would you manage the latter case?

Comment: I wanna set it up so that the RasPi can connect to one specific WiFi, but does not need to connect to a network for it to create the bunch of networks. I am not exactly sure how I would manage the latter case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to achieve this is to get hostapd and create a bunch of ssids in the config files. At the bottom of your `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`, you would want to put

```
bss=wlan0_0
ssid=thisisthefirstone

bss=wlan0_1
ssid=thisisthesecondone
```

and so on for each on ssid that you want. I have not tested the limit of this yet. You can set passwords for it as if you would for a regular hostapd entry.

Comment: And they all are on the air at the same time?

Comment: Yes they are all on the air at the same time. That was the point of the original post.